# What are the conditions that ensure that a linear operator on a separable Hilbert space has a discrete spectrum and its eigenvectors form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, linear-transformations, quantum-mechanics

I am particularly interesed in answers such as:

- symmetric, bounded, positive.
- self-adjoint and bounded
- essentialy self-adjoint and positive.

(Those were invented)

I'm interested in this question in the frame of Quantum mechanics.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You wrote *symmetric, bounded*. Can we deduce from this that bounded does **not** imply fully defined in your notation? (Because then you could write bounded, self-adjoint as you did below.)

Comment: Yes, so bounded and self-adjoint implies discrete spectrum and eigenvector basis? Are there any cases where boundedness is not required?

Comment: I don't know, my question was only asking about your notation.

Comment: Bounded and self-adjoint do **not** imply a discrete spectrum.  For example, consider $A \in B(L^2[0,1])$ given by
$$
[A\varphi](t) = t\varphi(t)
$$
note also that this operator has no eigenvectors.

Comment: I have a hunch that the condition you're looking for is [Fredholm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_operator) with [index-0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Index).

Answer (score 1):

If the eigenvectors of $T$ form an orthonormal basis, the operator is necessarily normal. So, a necessary condition is that $T$ is densely defined and normal.

Since $Te_n-\lambda_ne_n$ for all eigenvectors $e_n$ and these form a basis, we have that $T=\sum_n\lambda _nP_n$, where the $P_n$ are projections. This doesn't characterize discrete spectrum, though, as the sequence $\{\lambda_n\}$ could have accumulation points.

For sufficient conditions, one could have

- $T$ is normal and finite-rank.
- $T$ is a linear combination of projections.

If we look for unbounded operators, the spectrum will have to be an unbounded sequence with no accumulation points. If $\lambda_0\in\mathbb C$ is not in $\sigma(T)$, then  $\lambda_0 I+T$ is invertible, and the spectrum of $(\lambda_0 I+T)^{-1}$ consists of a sequence $\{\lambda_n\}$ with $\lambda_n\to0$. This gives us another sufficient condition:

- For any $\lambda_0\not\in \sigma(T)$ the operator  $(\lambda_0 I+T)^{-1}$ is normal and compact.

The above condition is still not necessary: given a sequence of pairwise orthogonal infinite projections $\{P_n\}$, we can construct 
$$
T=\sum_n n\,P_n.
$$

Comment: If the eigenvalues form an *orthonormal* basis, then the operator is normal.

Comment: It's "eigenvectors". And yes, that's precisely the first sentence in my answer.

Comment: You said that only if "basis" means an orthonormal basis.

Comment: I see. Of course, I meant orthonormal. Why would anyone ever think of a non-orthonormal basis on a Hilbert space?

Comment: A inner product space can be finite-dimensional, and there you would probably assume the opposite, which would lead to a false theorem.

Answer (score 1):

For Quantum, a common condition on the Hamiltonian $H$ would be selfadjoint with compact resolvent. The Hamiltonian is typically unbounded, but the resolvent $R(\lambda)=(H-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is bounded by definition, and defined for $\lambda\notin\mathbb{R}$. For $\mu,\lambda\notin\sigma(A)$, the resolvent equation holds:
\begin{align}
             R(\lambda)&=R(\mu)+(\lambda-\mu)R(\lambda)R(\mu) \\
               &=\{ I+(\lambda-\mu)R(\lambda)\}R(\mu)
\end{align}
Because of this, if the resolvent is compact for some $\mu$, then it is compact for all $\lambda$. A compact resolvent has eigenvalues that can cluster only at $0$, which translates to eigenvalues for $H$ that can cluster only at $\infty$.

The Hamiltonian for the reduced mass Hydrogen isotope does not have a compact resolvent because its eigenvalues cluster at $0$ from below, and above that there is continuous spectrum. The Harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian has compact resolvent.